# Carry data across view model and populate buttons according to this data

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have created a Xamarin.Forms app that allows a user to login with a username & password. According to their username, their role is defined.

I have models as follows :

```
public class UserDetails
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool Truck { get; set; }
        public bool Car { get; set; }
        public bool Bus { get; set; }
}

public class TransportDetails
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a created a basic list that contains hard coded data as follows:

```
 public List<UserDetails> GetAllUserDetails()
 {
     List<UserDetails> userDetails = new List<UserDetails>
     {
        new UserDetails
         {
                    Id = 1,
                    Username = "admin",
                    Password = "123",
                    Truck = false,
                    Car = true,
                    Bus = true
                },
                new UserDetails
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Username = "superadmin",
                    Password = "123",
                    Truck = true,
                    Car = false,
                    Bus = true
                }
            };

     return userDetails;
}
```

I also have a list that contains data about the Transports :

```
public List<TransportDetails> GetAppDetails()
{
   List<TransportDetails> transportDetails = new List<TransportDetails>
        {
    new TransportDetails
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Truck",
        UrlAndroid = "http://192.168.11.15/apps/truck"
        },
        new TransportDetails
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Car",
            UrlAndroid = "http://192.168.11.15/apps/car"
        },
        new TransportDetails
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Bus",
            UrlAndroid = "http://192.168.11.15/apps/bus"
        };

  return transportDetails;
}
```

Now in my `LoginViewModel`, I check the login credentials and navigate to another page, as follows:

```
 public void CheckLogin()
        {
            Data data = new Data();

            allUsers = new List<UserDetails>();

            allUsers = data.GetAllUserDetails();

            if (allUsers.Any(x => x.Username.Equals(Username) && x.Password.Equals(Password)))
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage(Username));
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Invalid credentials", "OK");
            }
        }
```

What I want to achieve is that, when checking the credentials, if the credentials is correct, I want to get the corresponding data of the Transport Details that the user is entitled to get.

Like for user `Admin`, he is entitled to get data for `Car` and `Bus`. How can I pass these data through the constructor whilst navigating to the `MainPage` ?

Please help.

Comment: instead of passing just their UserName to MainPage, pass their UserDetails object

Comment: How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of passing just their UserName to MainPage, pass their UserDetails object

```
if (allUsers.Any(x => x.Username.Equals(Username) && x.Password.Equals(Password)))
{
    var user = allUsers.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(Username) && x.Password.Equals(Password)).First();
    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage(user));
}
```

Comment: How can I get the corresponding data of the Transport Details also ?

Comment: do the the same thing - query the ones you want and pass them as an argument to your page

Comment: I want to get buttons to appeared dynamically based on what property is true in the model `UserDetails` once a user has logged in. Then, when the buttons appeared based on what is `true` for this user, I want the button name and button value (url)  from  the `TransportDetails` model. Any idea on how can I achieve this ?

I'm totally confused here.

Comment: I checked the green mark. Its mentioned in this question itself. Please help if you can.

Comment: You are asking 2 different things - 1 question is about passing data between pages, the other is about dynamically building UI.  Please limit your questions to 1 per post